# vagrant up doesn't work with laravel/homestead

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, vagrant

Trying to vagrant up laravel homestead with provider virtual box, but get an error

```
Progress: 40%There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagr
ant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "\\\\?\\C:\\HashiCorp\\boxes\\laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead
\\7.0.0\\virtualbox\\box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "ubuntu-18.04-amd64_15
48008280989_91293", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "11", "--disk", "C:\\Users\\\u2567\
u044E\u044B\u2116\u0447\u044E\u0442\u0440\u0404\u0445\u044B\u2116\\VirtualBox VM
s\\ubuntu-18.04-amd64/ubuntu-18.04-amd64-disk001.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting \\?\C:\HashiCorp\boxes\laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead\7.0.0\virtual
box\box.ovf...
OK.
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...
Progress state: E_INVALIDARG
VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057) - One or more arguments ar
e invalid (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleImportAppliance(s
truct HandlerArg *)" at line 957 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't noticed, that I already have VM in virtualbox, called "homestead-7", but, how I understood, this VM was created with another project vagrant file, so this time I couldn't start it with vagrant up. I just deleted that VM and created new with vagrant up.